# If I put a ring of bar magnets around a wire, will a current be generated in the wire?

Tags: electromagnetism

By amperes law, the line integral of the magnetic field around a wire is given by ui. So if I put many rings of bar magnets around a wire, will a current be generated in it?

Comment: Just to clarify - how can bars be rings

Comment: Well, they can't, obviously. But I can take a lot of thin bar magnets and have them approximate a ring.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. Ampere's law relates to the magnetic field generated by a current i.e. *moving* electrons (e.g. the mag field observed around a current carrying conductor) and is applied to a steady current. The magnetic field you are applying comes from 'permanent' magnets, not as a result of current (although actually generated by electron spins aligned around atoms in the bar magnets) so Ampere's law is not really applicable to this magnetic field.

The simple answer to your question is no. You would not measure current in a wire with lots of bar magnets around it. However nothing is ever quite simple when you look closely. The placing of the ring of magnets around the wire would result in a changing magnetic field which would push the electrons in the wire inside the magnetic ring sideways i.e. generate a current. Unless the wire is a super-conducting closed circuit this current will only last while the magnets are being placed (conservation of energy, the current is lost immediately as heat due to wire resistance). You would have to keep increasing the magnetic field to keep getting current in normal wire. Decreasing the magnetic field to zero again would push the electrons in the opposite direction (in a superconductor this would cancel the current flowing, and I think you get back the energy you put in when placing the magnets).

Under normal circumstances:
An electric current will be generated in a conductor only by a *changing* magnetic field. Using the observed fact that "an electron moving into a downwards magnetic field is forced to the right" it is possible to visualise what is happening in many situations ("downwards" is defined as North pole above, South below). 
So if a wire that is moving in a magnet field, the electrons in it will have a *force* exerted on them at right angles to the direction of movement (electromotive force or EMF) and they will tend to move in that direction. If the direction they are being pushed in is along the wire (not across it's width) then this can be measured as a voltage at the ends of the wire, and if there is a connection between the ends of the wire a current will flow (as in a generator or alternator).
Similarly if a wire is in an magnetic field and the electrons in the wire are moving along it (i.e. there is a current flowing) the electrons will have a force exerted on them at right angles to the direction of movement and this is experienced as a sideways force on the wire (as in a motor).
Hope this helps :)